# SonarLint with Visual Studio

Tags: sonarlint-vs

I installed `SonarLint` plugin for Visual Studio. 
Can I perform code analysis with `SonarLint` without connecting to `SonarQube` server?

From other blogs, I understand "code analysis" option is shown in menu. But this option is always available in Visual studio, even without this plugin and I think this is Visual studio code analysis. Is there any Sonar analysis that can be done just by installing `SonarLint` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

`Is there any Sonar analysis that can be done just by installing SonarLint plugin.`

Yes. It will not be as robust as the scans performed by SonarQube server, but SonarLint has inline scanning that builds upon the native functionality of visual studio (or whatever supported IDE for that matter).

You can prove it to yourself - include SonarLint in your solution, but without connecting to a sonar server instance. Try out any of the rules, like `S100   Methods and properties should be named in camel case` (click References -> right click Analyzers -> Open Active Ruleset -> select the checkbox for S100). If you then create a method `STUFFthingsSTUFF()` you will get green line highlighting with a description telling you that it does not abide by camel case standards. Remove the rule and the highlighting goes away.